# How wait for page finish reloading in cypress after click?

Tags: cypress

I got form and when I trigger click on submit button this cause to refresh current page. After that I would like to do some assertions. How I know that page finished refreshing and I can start to searching an element?

```
cy.get('#formButton').click() // adds new item and refresh page
// do assertions on page
```

Comment: Check this question, it will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50685393/1085483

Answer (score 2):

This solution was [posted by @msty on a similar GitHub issues](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1805#issuecomment-479430965):

```
// Navigate / submit form
cy.click('#someButtonToNavigateOnNewPage');

cy.location('pathname', {timeout: 10000})
  .should('include', '/newPage');

// Do assertions here
cy.contains('h1', 'success')
```

Another solution from the [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Time) is:

```
// Wait for the route aliased as 'getAccount' to respond
// without changing or stubbing its response
cy.server()
cy.route('/accounts/*').as('getAccount')
cy.visit('/accounts/123')
cy.wait('@getAccount').then((xhr) => {
  // we can now access the low level xhr
  // that contains the request body,
  // response body, status, etc
})
```

Answer (score -4):

5 ways:

1) Make SPA without refresh and use callback/promise after change DOM;

2) Set cookie, refresh page, each time when page loaded use condition like:

```
if (existsRefreshCookieAfterFormSubmit()) { ...
```

3) Just block form sending like:

```
form.onsubmit = function() { return false; };
```

4) Use `<a>` instead `<button>` or `<input>`

5) Don't use `<form>` as parent of inputs, use inputs only.