# Avoid using cy.wait() to wait for a page to load due to aborted get request cypress

Tags: node.js, timeout, cypress

I'm running a cypress test that requires a page to load before clicking an element and logging in, but for some reason a failed (and aborted) GET request is causing the page to take forever to load and eventually it times out unless I add a cy.wait(6000) before the cy.click() call. I need to somehow wait for the page to load without using a cy.wait(). How can I do this, given that I cant fix the aborted GET request?

[image]

```
  cy.visit(loginUrl)
  cy.url().should('contain', '#/loginPortal')
  cy.wait(6000) //Allows page to load before trying to log in, needs to be removed
  cy.contains('ButtonText').click()
```

Comment: This is a common request [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50525143/927631) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553489/in-cypress-how-do-i-wait-for-a-page-to-load) [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47299968/927631) with no silver bullet solution. One [potential workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304163/927631), but not simple.

Answer (score 7):

You can make Cypress wait for any specific XHR call, before you assert. How long it waits is defined by the [responseTimeout configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts).

```
cy.server();
cy.route('**/api/getData').as('getData');
cy.visit('/home');
cy.wait('@getData');
cy.contains('ButtonText').click()
```

[Cypress best practices: Unnecessary-Waiting.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting)

[Cypress docs on wait Alias.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias)

Answer (score 4):

It's useful to tell Cypress to wait for a specific URL to be present in the address bar before continuing.

```
cy.get('#login').click();
cy.location('pathname', {timeout: 20000}).should('include', '/path/to/page');
```

This can be used to wait for redirects which are triggered after login or any page change.  That may be a necessary first step before using cy.wait for an XHR request, as Rui Marques describes.